# cakephp update field with not(field)

Tags: cakephp, sql-update

I have this query 
UPDATE comments SET like=NOT(like) WHERE userid=12345

Howto with cakephp ?

I tried

```
$update=array('like NOT' => '(like)');
$conditions=array('userid' => 12345);  
$res = $this->updateAll($update,$conditions);
```

but not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$update = array('like' => '1-like');
$conditions = array('userid' => 12345);  
$res = $this->updateAll($update, $conditions);
```

Comment: with your sintax works only if like=false. If like=true the value remains true in table. I don't understand why

Comment: what type of value is `like` ? (0 / 1) ?

Comment: like is boolean (0/1)

Comment: can you try something like `like = 1 - like`, like in my answer?